# Entity Framework: DBContext Thread Error

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a class `CommonService` when I declare my context `_epdaDb` that I use in all  methods :

```
public class CommonService
{
    EPDA.WebApi.Context.EPDAContext.ApplicationDbContext _epdaDb = new Context.EPDAContext.ApplicationDbContext();
```

and a method :

```
public ResultMessage DeleteCountry(int id_country)
{
    ResultMessage result = new ResultMessage();

    var countryToRemove = _epdaDb.Countrys.Include("Towns").FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id_Country == id_country);           
    return result;
}
```

while I trying to test the `DeleteCountry` method I have an error :

> An exception of type System.InvalidOperationException occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code. The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

After a lot of research I did not found a great solution of that I just found that I should instantiate my context in every method.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Try to do it in constructor

Comment: do you mean adding the _epda = new .... in the Class Constructor ?

Comment: Yeap, try to use it inside constructor.

Comment: Ok thank you i will try but this is the first time that i have this issue and realy i don t have any idea to replicate it ,have you any idea ?. mayb make a lot of call to the same method ?

Comment: *Or* use a new `CommonService` instance in each thread. By the way, you don't show how you have multiple threads.

Comment: @GertArnold : this issue is caused when i call the same methode multiple time exactly in debug mode , i try to replicate it but all work fine now , i work now in the Dev Envir and even if it's work fine now  i will add a contructor to my classes because i think in the production Envir i will have a lot of request to the same ressource

Comment: Then each request should have its own CommonService instance. I suspect you use some static variable somewhere.

Comment: No i have no static variable , not for the moment

Comment: Hi ! i have always the problem even if i create a constructor , ithink it s problem in th debug mode